# How do I make an unbounded time interval index with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, infinity

I have a timeseries in pd.DataFrame format with its index being of datetime type.
I have another dataframe with a value (price) and an index which is a time interval. The last input of this price index must not have an end date. As long as I have not updated my price index, I want the last value to be valid forever in the future.

```py
import pandas as pd
str_date_list=[pd.to_datetime("2018-01-01"),pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01"),pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01")]
index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(str_date_list,closed='left')
price_index=pd.DataFrame(index=index,data={"test":[1,2]})
date_test=pd.to_datetime("2020-05-01")
price_index.loc[date_test][0]
```

In this example, I put 2020 as the end date, but in reality, I don't know the end date, and I don't want to write "3000-01-01", it's ugly.

Is there a way to make an unbounded datetime interval?
Is there a way to write pd.to_datetime(inf) or pd.to_datetime(-inf) properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not being strictly equivalent to the `inf` value that you requested, [pandas.Timestamp.max](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html#pandas-timestamp-max) could be a handy alternative?

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Timestamp.max
```

Gives back the maximum allowed value:

```
Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

Comment: and pd.Timestamp.min for the lower bound. Thanks, it's the answer I needed.

Comment: Is there a generalized version of this answer. What if the interval index has integer numbers instead of date and the last interval is unbounded ?